# Error ".NET Framework" – "queue was full" when running Open VPN Manager

Tags: windows-7, windows, .net-framework

Windows 7, 64-bit, 16 GB 1888 MHz RAM.

When launching some program, I get this error:

[image: “Microsoft .NET Framework” error window]

Meanwhile, I either cannot open up a web page at all or the web page will have only text and the formats; pictures, etc., are all messed up.

More detailed debug information as follows:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking
>   just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not
>   be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or
>   because a queue was full
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ExclusiveTcpListener.Start(Boolean
>   exclusiveAddressUse)
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.StartListening(Object
>   data)
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupChannel()
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary
>   properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider,
>   IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary
>   properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider,
>   IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.RegisterChannel(Boolean
>   SecureChannel)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)
>
> at OpenVPNManager.Program.Main(String[] args)

BTW I haven't installed any Windows .NET IDE or anything and this isn't caused by my program, and please rule out of insufficient RAM because this happens when there are 12 GB of available RAM.

Comment: Windows 7 comes pre-installed with .Net Framework but you would **only** get this error if you were running a .Net application

Comment: Cross site related: https://serverfault.com/questions/661476/getting-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lack. Check the programs you're currently using, there may be a port leak or port exhaustion when an application makes too many outgoing connections in short period without disposing them properly.

Comment: Hello @Ramhound  Can I update to a newer .net framework to solve this? Or stop and start a/several windows service(s) for this?

Comment: I know nothing about your application.  So that question isn't answerable

Comment: Voting to leave open because this is a known issue. See Magicandre's answer.

Comment: @music2myear: I was just about to Vote To Close as Unclear because the question title says “when running Open VPN Manager” but the question body says “When launching some program” — but then I saw that you introduced that discrepancy. Are you sure that your edit doesn’t muddy the waters?

Comment: The issue appears to be specific to Open VPN Manager as evidenced by the answer and the details in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This message comes from the application [OpenVPNManager](https://github.com/jochenwierum/openvpn-manager) where the developer didn't handle the [System.Net.Sockets.SocketException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx) in his code.

Create a [new issue](https://github.com/jochenwierum/openvpn-manager/issues/new) in the bugtracker so that it can be fixed.